# Compatible PIP version for python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

There's my workaround

1. I installed python 3.4.3 32bit version it comes with PIP version 6.0.8
2. I wanted to upgraded my pip with: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
   And it installed pip latest version 20.0.2
3. I downloaded some wheels `opencv-python` from this link https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv. In my case I downloaded opencv_python‑3.1.0‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl this wheel file
4. When I install downloaded wheel using upgraded pip. I got error about: PIP required python version 3.6 or higher

It seems PIP version 20.0.2 doesn't works with python 3.4
So which is the compatible version for python 3.4?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at `pip`'s [changelog](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/):

> #### 19.2 (2019-07-22)
>
> #### Deprecations and Removals
>
> Drop support for EOL Python 3.4. ([#6685](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6685))

The last version supporting Python 3.4 is thus 19.1.1.